# how can I use Python WatchDog to find out who changed the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is the simplest script that shows when it was changed, but how do I get detailed information? For example, who changed it with reference to the directory.
`

```
import sys
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while observer.isAlive():
            observer.join(1)
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

`

please with examples.

I looked at the manual on watchdog, but did not understand how to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

The watchdog works via inotify mechanism and will only notify you that a file had been changed, created or deleted. There is no information in the filesystem about who did the change. The information you have is basically the same information that you would get by looking at a directory listing such as with `ls -al`.

Assuming you are working on Linux, a file has an owner and a group. Typically, they are set according to the UID/GID of a process that creates the file, and remain unchanged even if a process with another UID/GID modifies the file (unless explicitly changed with `chmod/chgrp`).

To track filesystem changes in more detail, you probably need to use the audit subsystem, but that's a completely different story.

Comment: I have Linux, but I need to track it on Windows. They are not satisfied with the local security policy. Are there no ready-made libraries? And where can I try to get this information from? 

They have folders and network drives open for public access there.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This kind of tracking should generally be implemented on application level. If you are just sharing folders via SMB to the public, that's going to be very difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. You are absolutely right.